# how to express an integral with dy`s?

Tags: calculus

originally if we were givin the following information $y=e^x , x=0, y=4$. If we were to find the area with these requirments we would simply do a integral from zero till ln4 of $4-e^xdx$
I dont understand how would somone express the same area using integrals in terms of dy

Answer (score 1):

It will be
$$\int_1^4 xdy $$ with $$x=\ln (y) $$

we find
$$\int_1^4 \ln (y)dy=$$
$$[y\ln (y)-y]_1^4=$$
$$4\ln (4)-4+1$$